# Tabs in Angular Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm trying to just display a couple of tabs by using Angular Bootstrap, but I cannot see any content displayed. All I see is a blank white page.

Where am I wrong?

**html-**

```
<html ng-app = 'myApp'>
  <head>
     <title>Chat</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div ng-controller="Tabs">
     <tabset>
        <tab heading="Static title">Static content</tab>
        <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}"   active="tab.active">
         {{tab.content}}
        </tab>  
     </tabset>   
   </div>

<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="app.js"></script>

</body>    
</html>
```

**app.js:** My controller is here

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.bootstrap']);


myApp.controller('Tabs', function ($scope, $window) {
  
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
    { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
  ];


});
```

I ensured that I loaded all the scripts properly. But why is that the tabs are not displayed? Where did I go wrong?

### Edit

Console in my browser reads this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tab.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10514
angular.js:12330 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tab.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10514:11
    at sendReq (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10333:9)
    at serverRequest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10045:16)
    at processQueue (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14567:28)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14583:27
    at Scope.$eval (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15846:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15657:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15951:24)
    at bootstrapApply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1633:15)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330
angular.js:10514 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tab.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10514
angular.js:12330 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tab.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10514:11
    at sendReq (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10333:9)
    at serverRequest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10045:16)
    at processQueue (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14567:28)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14583:27
    at Scope.$eval (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15846:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15657:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15951:24)
    at bootstrapApply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1633:15)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330
angular.js:10514 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tabset.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10514
angular.js:12330 Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/template/tabs/tabset.html'.
    at Error (native)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10514:11
    at sendReq (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10333:9)
    at serverRequest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:10045:16)
    at processQueue (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14567:28)
    at file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:14583:27
    at Scope.$eval (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15846:28)
    at Scope.$digest (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15657:31)
    at Scope.$apply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:15951:24)
    at bootstrapApply (file:///C:/Users/NIKHIL/Desktop/angular/node_modules/angular/angular.js:1633:15)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330
2angular.js:12330 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/tabs/tab.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Ftabs%2Ftab.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:17530)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
    at angular.js:14583
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1633)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4450)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1631)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330
angular.js:12330 Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: template/tabs/tabset.html (HTTP status: undefined undefined)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$compile/tpload?p0=template%2Ftabs%2Ftabset.html&p1=undefined&p2=undefined
    at angular.js:68
    at handleError (angular.js:17530)
    at processQueue (angular.js:14567)
    at angular.js:14583
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15846)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15657)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15951)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1633)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4450)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1631)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12330
```

### Edit 2

I included
`<script src="ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js"></script>` in my code now. All the errors have gone.

**This is what is displayed:**

[image]

**This is the expected result:**

[image]

Comment: See [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for bootstrap and search Tabs

Comment: Oh yes, I did. I wrote this code only based on the demo example provided there.

Comment: do you see any error in console?

Comment: Make sure you're properly referencing angular bootstrap ui. Works fine here: http://codeply.com/go/xIhx7J8Ylh

Comment: Ok. @Skelly Can you please point me to the bootstrap ui file? If I download from the main site, I'm only getting a single file - "-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1" . But using npm I'm getting a folder with many files. I'm confused. What should I import to use angular bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

or

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

You should load boostrap

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

add this between `<head>` and `</head>`

Comment: Hi @Vishnu, I tried the suggestion. It didn't work but the error changed to "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND". It is saying that it  can't find the file "angular/template/tabs/tab.html". Any help please?

Comment: Please see my edit. What file should I import to use angular bootstrap in first place, please?

Comment: Thanks @Vishnu. I didn't think that we need to link bootstrap separately, since we are already using angular-bootstrap. Thanks for your help! :)